# Time modification linux c++

Tags: c++, time

I am trying to get the date of the last modification of the files of a folder in C++.
But I don't understand how I can replace "afile.txt" but a variable name.

When I replace "afile.txt" by something else I have got this error:

> proj.cpp: In function ‘Folder getdir2(std::string,
>   std::vector >&, std::string, std::string,
>   std::string)’: proj.cpp:325:25: error: cannot convert ‘const string
>   {aka const std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’
>   to ‘int stat(const char*, stat*)’
>            stat(t1, &attrib);   // get the attributes of afile.txt

Here is the code:

```
struct tm* clock;       // create a time structure
        struct stat attrib;     // create a file attribute structure    
        stat("afile.txt", &attrib);   // get the attributes of afile.txt
        clock = gmtime(&(attrib.st_mtime)); // Get the last modified time and put it into the time structure
```

Comment: This is what [references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) are for.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are attempting to pass a `std::string` to `stat`. `stat` is a C function, and as such only accepts `const char *` (a "C" string) as input.

Use the `.c_str()` method of `std::string` to get a C string:

```
std::string filename;
...
stat(filename.c_str(), &attrib);
```